# Performance issue using regex to replace/clear substring

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

I have a string containing things like this:

```
<a@{style}@{class}@{data} id="@{attr:id}">@{child:content} @{child:whatever}</a>
```

Everything to do here is just clear `@{xxx}`, except sub-strings starting with `@{child: .`

I used `str.match()` to get all sub-strings `"@{*}"` in an array to search and keep all `@{child: substrings:`

```
var matches = str.match(new RegExp("@\{(.*?)\}",'g'));
if (matches && matches.length){
    for(var i=0; i<matches.length; i++){
        if (matches[i].search("@{child:") == -1) str = str.replace(matches[i],'');  
    }
}
```

I got it running ok, but it's too slow when string becomes bigger (~2 seconds / +1000 nodes like this one on top)

Is there some alternative to do it, maybe using a rule (if exists) to escape `@{child:` direct in regex and improve performance?

Comment: For a start, try using `indexOf` instead of `search` to check if the match starts with `@{child:`

Comment: I tried it already. Got almost same results using search.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you don't want to remove the `@{child:...}` sub-strings but everything else of the format `@{...}` should go. In which case can you could change the regular expression to check that `child:` is not matched when you perform the replace:

```
var str = '<a@{style}@{class}@{data} id="@{attr:id}">@{child:content} @{child:whatever}</a>';
str = str.replace(/@\{((?!child:)[\s\S])+?\}/g, '');
```

This seems pretty fast.

Comment: Yes It's faster... but I realized what is the problem: use RegEx class. Is there another way to convert strings to pattern (sometimes this pattern must be parameterized)?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "sometimes this pattern must be parameterized"? And can you clarify what the problem with the RegEx class is? Is it still a performance issue? If it's performance related it would be useful to see a code example (with the large string) that is performing too slowly and get an idea of what is acceptable performance.

Comment: _“Is there another way to convert strings to pattern (sometimes this pattern must be parameterized)?”_ – of course you can go and try to implement this using “normal” string functions only – but I doubt this will be faster than using regex (but probably rather the opposite). In the end, it might just be that your data set is too large for any “better” performance to begin with. That would mean, either use it on less data, or use another implementation (maybe put it into a web worker, or not even JS at all.)